# Getting list of installed programs does not work

Tags: powershell

I am a bit confused why it's not working.
I am trying to get a list of the installed programs on client machines with powershell with the following script:

```bsh
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object Name,vendor,Version,InstallDate
```

Which on my local machine works fine, but running it on client machines outputs blank.

I have tried some other scripts I've found on the internet, but they require admin rights which a normal user doesn't have.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Do you run it directly on the machines or do you use remoting?

Comment: iam running it directly on the machines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i haven't found the reason why this is happening i found out that if i ran

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*  | Select-Object DisplayName,Publisher,Version,InstallDate | Sort-Object -Property InstallDate -Descending | Out-String
```

I could get a List of 64 bit programms

and with

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*  | Select-Object DisplayName,Publisher,Version,InstallDate | Sort-Object -Property InstallDate -Descending | Out-String
```

i could get a list of 32 bit programms

This solved the problem for me.